# Refresh JSON using PHP (Weather Underground API)

Tags: php, json

I'm using the Weather Underground API to show live weather data on a PHP page. However, I'd like to have the weather values automatically refresh every 5 minutes (as opposed to refreshing the entire web page). Is there a way for the values to refresh themselves (ie. temperature, wind, etc)?

I'm calling the information like this:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('http://api.wunderground.com/api/[key]/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/TX/Austin.json');
    $json_b = json_decode($json_string);
```

Forgive the question; I'm still very new to all this, and couldn't find an answer that worked in my coding. Thanks

Comment: JS code on your page invokes a php script which does basically `echo file_get_contents('....'))`. your JS code then takes the returned json data and integrates it into your page.

Comment: I'm sorry; I'm still unclear. Does that mean I should use a JS code to call for the data to be refreshed? I noticed some questions regarding jQuery, but again, I'm still new to this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Comment: Thanks for the link. I understand I still need to learn A LOT more about Ajax programming, but was looking for more of a quick solution to my problem since I don't have a lot of time this weekend.

Comment: use jquery(). it's damn easy. your php script would pretty literally be just `<?php echo file_get_contents(... the wunderground url); ?>`, and the jquery would be `$.getJSON('... address of your script...')`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/